# Why separate site for judaism?

Tags: discussion, scope

Why this part of StackExchange is only for judaism and not about all religions with tags for every particular?

Comment: Why a site about religion? Or math? Or linguistics? Why not just one about life - or better, existence - or just one meta site about everything _and nothing_ with tags?

Comment: @SethJ. Forty-two. The answer is forty-two.

Comment: @TRiG, yes, but what is the question?

Answer (score 11):

From the [Area51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Should my idea be part of an existing site, or its own site?
>
> In general, if a site makes sense as part of a bigger site, it's better to have one big site than a bunch of little niche sites. Site X should be subsumed by site Y if:
>
> - Almost all X questions are on-topic for site Y
> - If Y already exists, it already has a tag for X, and nobody is complaining
> - You're not creating such a big group that you don't have enough experts to answer all possible questions
> - There's a high probability that users of site Y would enjoy seeing the occasional question about X

Based on this (particularly points 3 and 4) it makes sense to me that any religion can have its own site. There are other religion based sites such as [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/) and [Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/) as well as proposals for [Hinduism](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29980/hinduism), [Buddhism](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45110/buddhism), [Spirituality](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41280/spirituality), and apparently even [Satanism](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42941/satanism).

Comment: why only judaism is shown in the bottom of SE pages?  Where is links for all others?

Comment: @Alkant [Christianity.SE] and [Islam.SE] are both still in [beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq#beta), and [SE only includes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106471/179) links to sites that have graduated out of beta on the footer other sites that have done so, while beta sites are linked on each others' footers.

Comment: @Alkant You can see the full list of SE sites here: http://stackexchange.com/sites